# How to set the consistency level in Cassandra using node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I use node.js version 6.9.2 and Cassandra 3.9.

I would like to set a consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM for all my queries when creating the Client instance.

According to [this documentation](http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/getting-started/), I need to do like the following.

```
const client = new Client({ queryOptions: { consistency: types.consistencies.quorum } });
```

I changed the consistency level of quorum to local_quorum.

```
const client = new Client({ queryOptions: { consistency: types.consistencies.local_quorum } });
```

However, when I start my app with this snippet of code, I receive an error.

```
ReferenceError: types is not defined
```

So, without fully understanding this meaning, I set text in place of types.

```
const client = new Client({ queryOptions: { consistency: text.consistencies.local_quorum } });
```

I received another error.

```
ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

My questions are:

What should be the value of `types`?

Is changing the `quorum` to `local_quorum` necessary to have the consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM? If it isn't, what is the correct way to assign LOCAL_QUORUM to my queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type consistency is suppose to be `types.consistencies.localQuorum` if i remember correctly :)

Adding more info:
The types is Inside the driver requirement to access it you need to declare it before

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['host1'] });
client.connect(function (err) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  client.execute(query, params, { consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.localQuorum }, function (err) {
      //This callback will be called once it has been written in the number of replicas
      //satisfying the consistency level specified.
    });
});
```

Comment: I still get this message 'ReferenceError: types is not defined'.

Comment: and you are using the cassandra_driver like this to call the consistencies?

Comment: `var cassandra_drv = require('cassandra-driver');
cassandra_drv.types.consistencies.localQuorum`

Comment: It worked after adding cassandra_drv in front of types. Thank you.